# How do I upload folders via FTP PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing a script that can FTP files and folders using PHP functionality.

I'm able to upload files via ftp but not folders, is is possible to upload folders via PHP Ftp

My file code looks similar to below

```
$upload = ftp_put($connection, '123test.co.za/images/1.jpg','1.jpg', FTP_ASCII);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [manual page](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.mkdir.php), has code showing how to do it using [ftp_mkdir](http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/function.ftp-mkdir.php).